# When is filtering in Ember performed?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is my route model:

```
// routes/filter-categories.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        this.store.findAll('product');
        var products = this.store.filter('products', function (product) {
            console.log('filtering product %o', product.get('id'));
            ...
        });
        return products;
    },
});
```

Basically, I need al products when I enter the `filter-categories` route, and then I need to perform some client-side filtering on those products.

Taking a look at the console log, the first time I visit the `filter-categories` route, I see the following:

```
filtering product "101"
filtering product "102"
filtering product "103"
...
filtering product "101"
...
filtering product "101"
...
filtering product "101"
...
```

Each product gets filtered up to 4 times on first entering (the order of processing the products is actually not deterministic). I was expecting that each product gets filtered only once!

From here on, things get even worse: each time that I enter the `filter-categories` route, the filtering is performed once more for each product. So at some point I have:

```
filtering product "101"
filtering product "102"
filtering product "103"
...
filtering product "101"
filtering product "101"
filtering product "101"
filtering product "101"
filtering product "101"
filtering product "101"
...
filtering product "102"
filtering product "102"
filtering product "102"
filtering product "102"
filtering product "102"
filtering product "102"
...
```

(and now it looks deterministic)

If instead I request the products in the application route:

```
// routes/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.store.findAll('product');
    },
    ...
});
```

then I start the application on the top URL and then transition to my `filter-categories` route (which has no more `this.store.findAll('product');`), I get the following log:

```
filtering product "101"
filtering product "102"
filtering product "103"
...
```

Which is what I was expecting. But this has the problem that I am requesting the `products` in the application route, where I actually do not need them, just to work around some Ember strange behavior.

I would like to understand what is going on here, in order to implement this properly.

I assume that this has to do [with the fact that](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter):

> If any of a record's properties change, or if it changes state, the
>   filter function will be invoked again to determine whether it should
>   still be in the array.

But still I can not fully get what is going on. Why is the number of filtering rounds increasing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the order of you code is wrong findAll is an asynchonous call it´s not done after you called it, there´re several options to handle this

```
1. I wouldn´t do it
this.store.findAll('product').then(function(results) {
    var filtedResults = results.filter(function(product) {
        if (condition) {
            return true; //added to array
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return filteredResults;
});

2. route
model() {
    return this.store.findAll('product');
}

// in controller *value=value to observe for changes to determine if the model should be contained in products array
filteredProducts: Ember.computed('model.[]', 'model.@each.value', function() {
    var filtedResults = this.get('model').filter(function(product) {
        if (condition) {
            return true; //added to array
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return filtedResults;
}),

//template
{{#each filteredProducts as |product|}}
    {{product}}
{{/each}}
```